# How to run launch file with many packages

Tags: roslaunch, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i wrote launch file which use some different packages and i want to do one file which contains folders with this packages and folder "launch", where this launch file exist (3 folders with packages + 1 folder with launch files). I cant run this launch file cause i got error:

```
RLException: [allTags.launch] is neither a launch file in package [tag_detector_ros] nor is [tag_detector_ros] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I was trying with catkin_make and source devel/setup.bash. Can someone tell me how can I do it correctly?

LaunchFile:

```
<launch>
 <arg name="tag" default="1" />
 <group if="$(eval tag == 1)">
 <include file="$(find package_name)/launch/launch_file_name.launch"/>
 </group>

<group if="$(eval tag == 2)"> 
<include file="$(find package_name)/launch/launch_file_name.launch"/>
</group> 
</launch>
```

output of rospack find tag_detector_ros:

```
[rospack] Error: package 'tag_detector_ros' not found
```

output of find $(rospack find tag_detector_ros) -name *.launch:

```
[rospack] Error: package 'tag_detector_ros' not found
./src/image_pipeline/stereo_image_proc/launch/stereo_image_proc.launch
./src/image_pipeline/image_proc/launch/image_proc.launch
./src/usb_cam/launch/usb_cam-test.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/aruco_ros/aruco_ros/launch/aruco_marker_finder_kinect.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/aruco_ros/aruco_ros/launch/double.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/aruco_ros/aruco_ros/launch/marker_publisher.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/apriltags2_ros/apriltags2_ros/launch/continuous_detection.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/apriltags2_ros/apriltags2_ros/launch/single_image_client.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/apriltags2_ros/apriltags2_ros/launch/single_image_server.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/launch/allTagsTogether.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/launch/allTags.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/vision_visp/visp_auto_tracker/launch/tracklive_usb.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/vision_visp/visp_auto_tracker/launch/tracklive_usb_dataMatrix.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/vision_visp/visp_auto_tracker/launch/tracklive_firewire.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/vision_visp/visp_auto_tracker/launch/tutorial.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/vision_visp/visp_camera_calibration/launch/lagadic_grid.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/vision_visp/visp_tracker/launch/start.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/vision_visp/visp_tracker/launch/flea2/config.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/vision_visp/visp_tracker/launch/flea2/camera-nodelet.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/vision_visp/visp_tracker/launch/hrp2014/config.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/vision_visp/visp_tracker/launch/hrp2014/camera.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/vision_visp/visp_tracker/launch/hrp2014/camera-nodelet.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/vision_visp/visp_tracker/launch/hrp2014/image_pipeline.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/vision_visp/visp_tracker/launch/tutorial-multi.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/vision_visp/visp_tracker/launch/tutorial-nodelet.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/vision_visp/visp_tracker/launch/tutorial.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/vision_visp/visp_tracker/launch/uvc/config.launch
./src/tag_detector_ros/vision_visp/visp_tracker/launch/uvc/camera-nodelet.launch
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317813/how-to-run-launch-file-with-many-packages/) by [Filip4](https://answers.ros.org/users/40082/filip4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-03-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:\

> Can someone tell me how can I do it correctly?

WIthout seeing the launchfile? No.

**Comment by [Filip4](https://answers.ros.org/users/40082/filip4/) on 2019-03-06**:
Just a simple launchfile with including others launchfile (from this additional packages). Even if launch file is empty error occurs. Added launchfile code on main post.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
Please also show us the exact steps you perform (building workspace, sourcing it and invoking `roslaunch`).

**Comment by [Filip4](https://answers.ros.org/users/40082/filip4/) on 2019-03-06**:
catkin_make -> source devel/setup.bash -> roslaunch package_name launch_file_name

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
That is paraphrasing. Exact commands mean: copy-paste.

**Comment by [Filip4](https://answers.ros.org/users/40082/filip4/) on 2019-03-06**:
catkin_make,
source devel/setup.bash,
roslaunch tag_detector_ros allTags.launch

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-07**:
What is the output of `rospack find tag_detector_ros` and `find $(rospack find tag_detector_ros) -name *.launch`?

**Comment by [Filip4](https://answers.ros.org/users/40082/filip4/) on 2019-03-07**:
Added on main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> [rospack] Error: package 'tag_detector_ros' not found
> ```

well it would seem that 'tag_detector_ros' is just not a package in your workspace, and looking at the output of the `find` command, it would appear to actually be a directory, containing other ROS pkgs (ie: `aruco_ros`, `apriltags2_ros`, `visp_auto_tracker`, etc).

`roslaunch` can only launch launchfiles from actual ROS packages, *or* if you don't have a package, you can provide it with an absolute path to a launch file.

In your case using the latter option would probably be possible. Something like this should work (provided there are no problems with the launch file itself):

```
roslaunch /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src/tag_detector_ros/launch/allTags.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2